# fluid grid problem

Tags: css, fluid-layout

I have a problem with my first fluid grid layout.
This layout looks displaced(varying width) in the most browsers. It works only in firefox.(not in e.g. chrome or opera)
I don't understand why.

Thanks

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Grid Test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      .col {
        float:left;
        background-color: grey;
        margin-left: 1%;
        margin-right: 1%;
        margin-top: 1px;
        margin-bottom: 1px;
        height: 50px;
        text-align: center;
      }

      .one_quater {
        width: 23%;
      }
      .two_quater {
        width: 48%;
      }
      .three_quater {
        width: 73%;
      }

      .one_thirds {
        width: 31.333%;
      }
      .two_thirds {
        width: 64.666%;
      }

      .one_half{
        width: 48%;
      }

      .one_full{
        width: 98%;
      }

      .clear {
        clear: both;
        display: block;
        overflow: hidden;
        visibility: hidden;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col one_full">
        1/1
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col one_thirds">
        1/3
      </div>
      <div class="col one_thirds">
        1/3
      </div>
      <div class="col one_thirds">
        1/3
      </div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>


    <div class="row">
      <div class="col two_thirds">
        2/3
      </div>
      <div class="col one_thirds">
        1/3
      </div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>


    <div class="row">
      <div class="col one_thirds">
        1/3
      </div>
      <div class="col two_thirds">
        2/3
      </div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>


    <div class="row">
      <div class="col one_half">
        1/2
      </div>
      <div class="col one_half">
        1/2
      </div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col one_quater">
        1/4
      </div>
      <div class="col one_quater">
        1/4
      </div>
      <div class="col one_quater">
        1/4
      </div>
      <div class="col one_quater">
        1/4
      </div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col two_quater">
        2/4
      </div>
      <div class="col one_quater">
        1/4
      </div>
      <div class="col one_quater">
        1/4
      </div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>


    <div class="row">
      <div class="col one_quater">
        1/4
      </div>
      <div class="col two_quater">
        2/4
      </div>
      <div class="col one_quater">
        1/4
      </div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col one_quater">
        1/4
      </div>
      <div class="col one_quater">
        1/4
      </div>
      <div class="col one_quater">
        1/4
      </div>
      <div class="col one_quater">
        1/4
      </div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>


    <div class="row">
      <div class="col one_quater">
        1/4
      </div>
      <div class="col three_quater">
        3/4
      </div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track. The reason for differing rendering has to do with [pixel rounding](http://www.positioniseverything.net/round-error.html) which is a problem for all browsers, especially IE.

Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ShaggyDude11/Yvjhz/) to see compatibility suggestions